# How to draw views using Canvas Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I am trying to draw views dynamically on click of button.On clicking the button,I got an `illegal state exception` saying; the specified view already has a parent.

Is this the right way to create views dynamically?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        draw = new DrawView(this);

        relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        createButton = new Button(this);
        relativeLayout.addView(createButton);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);

        createButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                relativeLayout.addView(draw);
                setContentView(draw);
            }
        });

    }

public class DrawView extends View
{
    Paint paint;

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
     relativeLayout.addView(draw);
     setContentView(draw);
```

with

```
     relativeLayout.addView(draw);
     relativeLayout.invalidate();
```

this will add your view into **relativeLayout** and invalidate it to refresh screen

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this

```
relativeLayout.addView(draw);
setContentView(draw);
```

You can add a view to only one layout at a time.  You can't add the same View to multiple ViewGroups (Layouts).  The code above add the 'draw' View as a child of the 'relativeLayout' when sets it as the content View (for whatever class 'this.' is).

You can add the View with either:

```
 relativeLayout.addView(draw);
```

or

```
 setContentView(draw);
```

Comment: for that case u have to create multiple view and add those view to the appropriate layouts.

Comment: @Prashanth: You can add multiple Views to a Layout (ViewGroup), just call the '.addView(View)' method repeatedly.  The issue here was adding the SAME View to multiple ViewGroups.